# HttpContext.Current.Request null in production

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

In my WCF app i have a Global.asax.cs with something like this to retrieve the base URL:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string baseURL = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer, UriFormat.Unescaped);
}
```

In my development box (localhost) it works fine. But when i push it to production the `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request` returns `null`.

Anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Yes the production app is hosted on IIS.

Comment: Why are you trying to use current request on application start event? Application may or may not be started by a request.

Comment: @liho1eye. doh! ofcourse! I feel really small now sorry, should i delete this post?

Comment: @liho1ye: please add as answer so i can give you the credit.

Comment: Sure, though it seems vcsjones' answer is more complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving comment into answer:

You should not be trying to access current request inside `Application_Start` event.

Answer (score 9):

This is likely because in development your App Pool is in "Classic" mode (or on IIS 6-).

In production, your App Pool is set to "Integrated". Integrated does not allow you to access the `Request` object in `Application_Start`.

Classic behavior allows this because the only way to start an ASP.NET application in Classic Mode is with the first request. In Integrated mode, the application may start by other means than a request (Such as application warm-up).

You can find more information on why, and how to fix this on [IIS's Website](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/11/10/Integrated-mode-Request-is-not-available-in-this-context-in-Application_5F00_Start.aspx).

Ultimately, you have two options:

1. Switch your AppPool to Classic Mode.
2. Do not access the `Request` object in Application_Start.